# Calling in functions in another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I  created a function to read in a csv file and then write some of the data from the csv file into another file. I had to manipulate some of the data in the original csv file before I write it. I will probably have to do that manipulation a lot during the next couple months so I wrote another function to just do that manipulation, but I am having trouble calling in the function in my other function.

this is the function I am trying to call in:

```
import sys
import math

def convLatLon(measurement): # should be in '##.####' format    
    tpoint=float(measurement)    
    point_deg=math.floor(measurement) # find the degree for lat and lon 
    dpoint=tpoint-point_deg #subtract the lat value from just the degs to get the                   decimal fraction
    pointmin=dpoint * 60 # find the degree mins

    npoint= str(point_deg) + str(pointmin)        
    print(npoint)
```

How do I call in this function in another function? They are currently in the same directory. I am used to Matlab and thought it would be a simple call in command but I can not seem to figure it out. Any help will be greatly apprectiated.

Shay

Comment: I think you mean to pass `tpoint` to `math.floor()`

Answer (score 3):

You can import the file (same as you imported `sys` and `math`).  If your function is in a file called `util.py`:

```
import util
util.convLatLon(37.76)
```

If the file is in another directory, the directory must be in your PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Is:

```
from <filename> import convLatLon
```

What you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to import the file.

If your function is defined in file myfile.py and you wan`t to use it from myotherfile.py, you should import myfile.py, like this:

`import myfile`

and then you can use the function like this:

`result = myfile.myfunc(myparms)`

If you want to get rid of the myfile prefix, import it like this:

`from myfile import myfunc`

Answer (score 0):

If you have this function saved in a file called `myconv.py`

```
from myconv.py import convLatLon
convLatLon("12.3456")
```